# Can somebody please tell me if I am using the wrong node js version?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have been trying to update nodejs for a long time now. When I run `node -v`, it tells me I am using: `v0.10.40`. But when I look at nodejs.org it says the `v7.4.0`?

I have cleaned the npm cache and done a reinstall with `sudo n stable` but still `v0.10.40`, and the last time that I updated npm it prompted me that my node version is too old and outdated.

What am I doing wrong. And can somebody tell me if `v0.10.40` is the current or an outdated version?

Answer (score 3):

You likely have two versions of node installed and in your path. If you are on OSX or linux, run `which node` (if on Windows, you may `npm i -g @raider/which`, and then run `which node`). This should give you the location of the old version of node.

Then run `mv path/to/old/node path/to/old/node.bak`, replacing with the actual path, and rerun `node --version` to see if it picks up the right version now.

**UPDATE**: If you are on Ubuntu or another Debian based Linux, you should install the latest with the following [commands](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions):

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

**UPDATE**: If you are using `nvm`, run `nvm install node` followed by `nvm use node` in a new terminal to get the latest that `nvm` supports.

Comment: Hi cchamberlain, if I run the `mv` command that you recommend above i get back: `-bash: /Users/USERNAME/.nvm/v0.10.40/bin/node: No such file or directory`

Comment: @molleweide Based on that it sounds like you are using `nvm` which has its own set of methods for setting node versions. Can you try `nvm install node` which is supposed to install the latest version of node.

Comment: Just before you replied I bumped into a thread that adviced me to run: `~ > nvm ls
       v0.10.40
       v0.12.15
         v6.4.0
default -> 0.10 (-> v0.10.40)
node -> stable (-> v6.4.0) (default)
stable -> 6.4 (-> v6.4.0) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)`

Comment: It looks like it doesn't have any node 7 versions installed. Could you try `nvm install node` and then `nvm use node`?

Comment: I just ran `nvm install node` and now `which node` returns: `/Users/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v7.4.0/bin/node`

Comment: `node --version` should give you `v7.4.0` now then, correct?

Comment: yes. but only in the window that I run the command. If I open up another window it sais command not found?

Comment: Per https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/576#issuecomment-65624981, it looks like you might need to add a couple lines to your `~/.bash_profile`: `export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm` and `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`

Comment: @molleweide before doing that, try running `nvm alias default node` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: i tested `~ > nvm alias default node
default -> node (-> v7.4.0)`. now i will try to add those lines to .bash_profile

Comment: `node -v
~ > node -v
v7.4.0
~ > ` I think that did it!!