# Wrong Node.js version detected

Tags: java, node.js, angular, spring, ubuntu

I am trying to combine my projects created with Spring and Angular using Maven
The problem is when with Node.js version,

```
[ERROR] Node.js version v8.11.3 detected.
[ERROR] The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v10.13 or v12.0.
```

When I am checking verson by `node -v` I have `v12.0.0.`

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04 and I am used nvm to install Node.js
How to upgare version of Node.js?

I tried:

- Completely remove from Ubuntu [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786015/how-to-remove-nodejs-from-ubuntu-16-04), after this I still can see version by `node -v`
- Upgrade by nvm [link](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/update-node-js-version)
- Bunch of solutions from stackoverflow: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41857238/can-somebody-please-tell-me-if-i-am-using-the-wrong-node-js-version) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42979222/nodejs-why-is-node-reporting-wrong-version) (do not know how to check in Ubutnu)

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/home/pawel/Pulpit/NoteItApp/noteIt-ng-app/src/main/web/node/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/pawel/Pulpit/NoteItApp/noteIt-ng-app/src/main/web/node/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.3.0
3 info using node@v8.11.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle noteit-ng-app@0.0.0~prebuild: noteit-ng-app@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle noteit-ng-app@0.0.0~build: noteit-ng-app@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle noteit-ng-app@0.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle noteit-ng-app@0.0.0~build: PATH: /home/pawel/Pulpit/NoteItApp/noteIt-ng-app/src/main/web/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/pawel/Pulpit/NoteItApp/noteIt-ng-app/node_modules/.bin:/home/pawel/Pulpit/NoteItApp/noteIt-ng-app/src/main/web/node:/home/pawel/.nvm/versions/node/v12.0.0/bin:/opt/maven/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:
9 verbose lifecycle noteit-ng-app@0.0.0~build: CWD: /home/pawel/Pulpit/NoteItApp/noteIt-ng-app
10 silly lifecycle noteit-ng-app@0.0.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'ng build' ]
11 silly lifecycle noteit-ng-app@0.0.0~build: Returned: code: 3  signal: null
12 info lifecycle noteit-ng-app@0.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: noteit-ng-app@0.0.0 build: `ng build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 3
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/pawel/Pulpit/NoteItApp/noteIt-ng-app/src/main/web/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:304:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/pawel/Pulpit/NoteItApp/noteIt-ng-app/src/main/web/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid noteit-ng-app@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd /home/pawel/Pulpit/NoteItApp/noteIt-ng-app/src/main/web
16 verbose Linux 5.3.0-61-generic
17 verbose argv "/home/pawel/Pulpit/NoteItApp/noteIt-ng-app/src/main/web/node/node" "/home/pawel/Pulpit/NoteItApp/noteIt-ng-app/src/main/web/node/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v8.11.3
19 verbose npm  v6.3.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 3
22 error noteit-ng-app@0.0.0 build: `ng build`
22 error Exit status 3
23 error Failed at the noteit-ng-app@0.0.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 3, true ]
```

Please advice.

Comment: Are you using a maven plugin to run node?

Comment: Hi Deadron, thank you for your feedback. In my project structure I have parent pom with no plugin and two child poms (one for front and one for back) with plugins. One for front is installing node. I am using this guide: https://dzone.com/articles/building-a-web-app-using-spring-boot-angular-6-and

Comment: Show us your relevant pom files.

Comment: [Main pom](https://github.com/P-Brzezinski/NoteItApp/blob/master/pom.xml). [Frontend pom](https://github.com/P-Brzezinski/NoteItApp/blob/master/noteIt-ng-app/pom.xml). [Backend pom](https://github.com/P-Brzezinski/NoteItApp/blob/master/noteIt-api/pom.xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your frontend pom you are using frontend-maven-plugin to manage your node installation. This means it installs its own version of node to use for the build The node version is specified by `<nodeVersion>v8.11.3</nodeVersion>`. Change the version to `v12.0.0`

Comment: Thanks Deadron! I assume I must go back to basics of Maven to avoid this kind of troubles in future. Have a good day!